# Add Specific Category Page Templates to WordPress with a Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

How do you add a category template via a Wordpress **plugin**. It needs to be for a specific category. So if the category is 'category-awesome' load 'category-awesome.php'. I've come across using the single template hook e.g:

```
add_filter('single_template', 'my_custom_template');
```

But haven't found anything for categories or a single category.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I solved it. Use the [template include filter hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include):

```
function category_awesome( $template ) {

  if (is_category( 'awesome' )) {
    $new_template = dirname(__FILE__) . '/custom-template-awesome.php';
      if ( '' != $new_template ) {
        return $new_template ;
      }
  }

  return $template;
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'category_awesome' );
```